# keypad code is not working and produces wrong numbers

Tags: arduino-uno

I have the following issues:

1) When i press for example number 7 on the keypad it shows a different number on the serial monitor 
2) The servo motor works for any combination of 4 numbers.

Code:
/*http://openhwdesign.comLock system using a Keypad
*/

```
#include <Password.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwrite-strings"
Servo myservo; //declare servo
Password password = Password( "5523" ); 

const byte ROWS = 4; // declare the rows of the keypad
const byte COLS = 3; // declare the columns of the keypad

// Define the Keymap

char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
{'1','2','3'},
{'4','5','6'},
{'7','8','9'},
{'*','0','#'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2,3,4,5}; // Connect keypad’s pins to these Arduino pins.
byte colPins[COLS] = {6,7,8}; // Connect keypad’s pins to these Arduino pins.

// Create the KeyPad
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
myservo.write(0);
pinMode(11, OUTPUT); //The green led is set as an output.
pinMode(12, OUTPUT); //The red led is set as an output.
myservo.attach(13); //The servo is connected to the digital pin 13.
keypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent); //Add an event listener for the KeyPad

}

void loop(){
keypad.getKey();
myservo.write(180); //why? what happens if you comment it? ###########################
//delay(5);
}

void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent eKey){
// When the KeyPad will be pressed, the results will appear on the serial monitor.
switch (keypad.getState()){
case PRESSED:
Serial.print("Enter: ");
Serial.println(eKey);
delay(10);

switch (eKey){
case '*':
checkPassword(); // Will check the password.
delay(1); // Delay used for stability.
break;

case '#':
password.reset(); //Will reset the password
delay(1); // Delay used for stability.
break;

default:
password.append(eKey); //Append any keypress that is not a ‘#’ nor a ‘*’.
delay(1);
}
}
}
void checkPassword(){

if (password.evaluate()){ //If the combination inserted is equal to the combination saved, the servo’ll rotate.
Serial.println("Accepted");
//delay(5000);
delay(10);
myservo.write(50); //was 140
delay(5000);

digitalWrite(11, HIGH); //Turn the green led on.
delay(500); //Wait 5 seconds.
digitalWrite(11, LOW); //Turn the green led off.

//break; // remove if trial did not work #####################try#####################
}
//break; // remove if trial did not work ##########################################
else{ //If the combination inserted isn’t equal to the combination saved, the servo will not rotate.
//delay(5000); delays response
Serial.println("denied");
delay(10);
//delay(5000);
myservo.write(20); // was 50
digitalWrite(12, HIGH); //Turn the green led on.
delay(5000); //Wait 5 seconds. was 500 /// 
digitalWrite(12, LOW); //Turn the green led off.

    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just change the keys array to get the correct values. The keypad you have is probably wired differently from the one in the article.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is just look at what the problem is.  Create a new sketch and paste this code into it.

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte ROWS = 4; // declare the rows of the keypad
const byte COLS = 3; // declare the columns of the keypad

// Define the Keymap
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = 
{
    {'1','2','3'},
    {'4','5','6'},
    {'7','8','9'},
    {'*','0','#'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {2,3,4,5}; // Connect keypad’s pins to these Arduino pins.
byte colPins[COLS] = {6,7,8};   // Connect keypad’s pins to these Arduino pins.

// Create the KeyPad
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent eKey)
{
    // When the KeyPad will be pressed, the results will appear on the serial monitor.
    switch (keypad.getState())
    {
    case PRESSED:
        Serial.print("Enter: ");
        Serial.println(eKey);
        delay(10);
        break;
    }
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    keypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent); //Add an event listener for the KeyPad
}

void loop()
{
    keypad.getKey();
    delay(20);
}
```

You should recognise it, its a reformatted version of your code (pretty code is easier to debug), but with only the keypad bits in.

Now load that onto your hardware and write down what number is shown when you press 1 three times.  Do it three times just to make sure its the same number and you haven't got something totally obscure happening. Repeat for the other 11 buttons.

If 7 and 3 always give you 3 and 6 then you have got your row and column wires crossed.
If 7 always gives you 1 and 9 always gives you 3 then the wires for row 4 and 2 are crossed over. etc
If you can't work out the patter post your findings and I'm sure someone will solve the puzzle.

As for problem 2, don't even go there until you know what you are typing. :)

Hope that helps